# Splash flows outside of Container/FlatButton - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I'm trying to get the splash to match the same shape as my Container that has a FlatButton as its child.

When pressed, the splash currently fills a different shape as shown here:

[image]

My code for the widget is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {

const RoundedButton( {this.buttonColor, this.buttonTitle, @required this.onPressed});

  final Color buttonColor;
  final String buttonTitle;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      height: 42.0,
      width: 200.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: buttonColor,
      ),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        child: Text(
          buttonTitle,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ClipRRect` widget which clips the underlying widget with rounded corners and by using `borderRadius` property and passing same `radius` as of parent widget ie, `Container`, ie, wrap the `FlatButton` with `ClipRRect` to achieve desired effect. Sample working code below:

```
body: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      height: 42.0,
      width: 200.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),  
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print('pressed');
        },
        child: Text(
          'Send',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
      ),
      )
    ),
```

Hope this answers your question.